# Passing python packages fetched from remote repository to spark submit/shell

Tags: python, pyspark, pip

I have a python library packaged as a zip file available in a remote repository (Artifactory) and I would like to pass it to the python path of a spark-shell or spark-submit using the coordinates of the package (name and version number). I am currently doing the same with jar files:

```
spark-shell --repositories https://artifactory.com/maven --jars group:jar-name:1.0
```

I would like to do something like this

```
spark-shell --repositories https://artifactory.com/pypi --jars zipname==1.0
```

which obviously doesn't work since `repositories` is supposed to be a maven repo and `jars` should be a jar name

I know I could download the zip file beforehand and add it to the `PYTHONPATH`, but it would be better if I could directly point to it through coordinates

Answer (score 1):

I found the way, you can pass a remote path to `--py-files`, like `--py-files http://host:path_to_file/library.egg`